# OrientDB - select propery field

Tags: orientdb

I created property codeLanguage and add custom field type with value "SQL,JavaScript".

```js
ALTER PROPERTY MyClass.codeLanguage CUSTOM type='SQL,JavaScript'
```

In query I used somthing like this:

```html
SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE codeLanguage['type'] = 'JavaScript'
```

I want to get value of propety field "type". I tyred this:

```html
SELECT codeLanguage['type'] FROM MyClass
```

But I get only records with single column "codeLanguage"

```html
+--------------+
| codeLanguage |
+--------------+
|   SQL        +
+--------------+
|   SQL        |
+--------------+
```

I want get smth like this:

```html
+--------------+
| codeLanguage |
+--------------+
|SQL,JavaScript+
+--------------+
```

How get only value property field value maybe as meta data?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To use `CUSTOM` data type, you should provide the marshall and unmarshall methods. See: [OrientDB - Supported Types](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Types.html).  What is your goal? As it is now, you can just use an `EMBEDDEDLIST` type. Here is an example:

```
create class MyClass extends v
create property MyClass.codeLanguage EMBEDDEDLIST
insert into MyClass(codeLanguage) values (['SQL','JavaScript'])
select * from MyClass where codeLanguage contains "JavaScript"
select codeLanguage from MyClass
```

The output of the last query:

[image: select codeLanguage from MyClass]

Comment: You not right unserstand me. I find solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28317179/4907397. This answer what I found.